# How to identify df in a list that only have ID but nothing else in it

Tags: r, lapply, purrr

I have a list of list like below:

```
lst<- list(`101-01-101` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", 
"101-01-101"), BRTHDTC = c("BRTHDTC", "1953-07-07"), SEX = c("SEX", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", 
"101-01-101"), DSDT = c("DSDT", "2016-03-14"), DSDT_P = c("DSDT_P", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), Visits = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", "101-01-101"
), Visit = c("Visit", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1"), VISND = c("VISND", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))), `101-02-102` = list(Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", 
"101-02-102"), BRTHDTC = c("BRTHDTC", "1963-07-02"), SEX = c("SEX", 
"Female")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", 
"101-02-102"), DSDT = c("DSDT", "2017-04-04"), DSDT_P = c("DSDT_P", 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
)), Visits = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", "101-02-102"
), Visit = c("Visit", NA), VISND = c("VISND", NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), `101-03-103` = list(
    Demographics = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", 
    "101-03-103"), BRTHDTC = c("BRTHDTC", "1940-09-11"), SEX = c("SEX", 
    "Male")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame")), DiseaseStatus = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", 
    "101-03-103"), DSDT = c("DSDT", NA), DSDT_P = c("DSDT_P", 
    NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
    "data.frame")), Visits = structure(list(SubjectID = c("SubjectID", 
    "101-03-103"), Visit = c("Visit", "Screening: -28 Days to Day 1"
    ), VISND = c("VISND", NA)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))))
```

I would like to change `subjectID` input to `NA` if a `df` in the list only have the value in `SubjectID` but `NA` for all other variables. what should I do?

I am thinking of counting none `NA` input for each `df`, if the value equals 1, then remove all records or change `SubjectID` to `NA`. I would like to still keep the col names, But how to do that?

In my example file, `101-02-102` should have Visits as empty `df`, and `101-03-103` should have `DiseaseStatus` as empty `df`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it is a nested list, use double `lapply`, and on the inner `list`, element, get the `colSums` of logical matrix on NA, check if it is equal to number of rows (`nrow`), then assing the SubjectID to NA, return the data

```
lst2 <- lapply(lst1, function(x) {x <- lapply(x, function(y) 
    {if(all(colSums(is.na(y[-1])) == nrow(y))) y$SubjectID <- NA_character_
          y}); x})
```

-output

```
lst2
$`101-01-101`
$`101-01-101`$Demographics
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female

$`101-01-101`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-01-101 2016-03-14 <NA>  

$`101-01-101`$Visits
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>
1 101-01-101 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA> 


$`101-02-102`
$`101-02-102`$Demographics
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-02-102 1963-07-02 Female

$`101-02-102`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 101-02-102 2017-04-04 <NA>  

$`101-02-102`$Visits
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID Visit VISND
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 <NA>      <NA>  <NA> 


$`101-03-103`
$`101-03-103`$Demographics
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX  
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1 101-03-103 1940-09-11 Male 

$`101-03-103`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID DSDT  DSDT_P
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> 
1 <NA>      <NA>  <NA>  

$`101-03-103`$Visits
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>
1 101-03-103 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 <NA>
```

---

For the updated case

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {x <- lapply(x, function(y)     
       {if(all(colSums(is.na(y[-1, -1])) == nrow(y[-1, ]))) 
        y$SubjectID <- NA_character_    
             y[-1,]})
 x})
```

Comment: what if  my real data is from 2 row? can I do sth like `colSums(is.na(y[-1,-"SubjectID"]))`?

Comment: @Stataq So you want to check only from the second row onwards, right?  But, there are some elements with only one row.  Do you want to keep it as it is

Comment: Yes, I would like to check row 2 and after, as row 1 I will put variable labels

Comment: @Stataq My doubt is when you have only a single row, what do you want to do those cases

Comment: In the example gave, all the datasets have only a single row

Comment: As I am binding variable label to the dataset, then each df will at least have 1st row for labels.

Comment: @Stataq Can you please update your post with a new data as it is not clear to me

Comment: Sure. Will do shortly.

Comment: @akun Just update the data code to include 2 rows

Comment: @Stataq Try `lapply(lst, function(x) {x <- lapply(x, function(y) 
      {if(all(colSums(is.na(y[-1, -1])) == nrow(y[-1, ]))) y$SubjectID <- NA_character_
            y[-1,]}); x})`

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Solution**

I have updated my solution based on new requirements by OP, so that `SubjectID` in second row will be `NA` provided that all other variables are also `NA`s.

```
library(purrr)

lst %>%
  map(~ .x %>% 
        map(~ if(all(is.na(.x[2, -1]))) {
          .x %>%
            mutate(SubjectID = if_else(row_number() == 1, SubjectID, NA_character_))
        } else {
          .x
        }))

$`101-01-101`
$`101-01-101`$Demographics
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
2 101-01-101 1953-07-07 Female

$`101-01-101`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
2 101-01-101 2016-03-14 NA    

$`101-01-101`$Visits
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>
1 SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
2 101-01-101 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 NA   


$`101-02-102`
$`101-02-102`$Demographics
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX   
2 101-02-102 1963-07-02 Female

$`101-02-102`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 SubjectID  DSDT       DSDT_P
2 101-02-102 2017-04-04 NA    

$`101-02-102`$Visits
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID Visit VISND
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 SubjectID Visit VISND
2 NA        NA    NA   


$`101-03-103`
$`101-03-103`$Demographics
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX  
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
1 SubjectID  BRTHDTC    SEX  
2 101-03-103 1940-09-11 Male 

$`101-03-103`$DiseaseStatus
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID DSDT  DSDT_P
  <chr>     <chr> <chr> 
1 SubjectID DSDT  DSDT_P
2 NA        NA    NA    

$`101-03-103`$Visits
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
  <chr>      <chr>                        <chr>
1 SubjectID  Visit                        VISND
2 101-03-103 Screening: -28 Days to Day 1 NA
```